# Force all columns to be strings in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
>>> data = {'col_1': ['1','2','3'], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
>>> df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) # <== I want to modify this statement

>>> df.dtypes
col_1     int64
col_2    object
dtype: object
```

Notice that `col_1` has been inferred as an `int64` column. Is there a simple was that I can do "forceType=object" for every column I have? The data is already pre-formatted and I do not need pandas to mark anything up.

Comment: The example you've posted should have raised `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`. Even if you modify `data` to something like `data = {'col_1': ['1','2','3','4'], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}`, `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)` is returning columns with `object` dtype (using Pandas version 0.24.0).  Could you please check your example to make the problem reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the lists are of equal length, you can specify a `dtype=object` argument to `from_dict`. `'object'` specifies that **no conversion** is to be done on the columns, so they are loaded as-is.

```
data = {'col_1': ['1','2','3'], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, dtype=object)

df
  col_1 col_2
0     1     a
1     2     b
2     3     c

df.dtypes

col_1    object
col_2    object
dtype: object
```

---

If unevenly sized lists are going to become a problem, you can load using the `'index'` orient in the same manner and transpose the result:

```
data = {'col_1': ['1','2','3'], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index', dtype=object).T
df

  col_1 col_2
0     1     a
1     2     b
2     3     c
3  None     d

df.dtypes

col_1    object
col_2    object
dtype: object
```